# recording username into table from session with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a database system developed in mysql and php, with a login system as well, im using sessions,however when a user adds a record I want it to also record the user who added it, im thinking sessions would allow me to do this but im lost interms of how to retrieve the username from the session and add it to a table: example of a simple insert:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

I want value 3 to be the username from the sessions, I am not sure how much more information  you need to help me to solve this, so ask as you see fit

Comment: If you are keeping username in the session then you can retrieve it but how you are keeping them ?

Comment: sessions are just data stuffed into $_SESSION that PHP magically preserves for you between script invocations. There's nothing different about pulling data out of the $_SESSION array than any other PHP variable, except the required session_start() to populate the array.

Comment: What information are you storing into your session? If you execute a var_dump($_SESSION); what would you get? If you store username into your $_SESSION array, then you can simply add it, if you store the user ID, you'll need to get his username through another request.

Comment: you would want to save the user id number into your session when they log in. you would then use this user id and attach it to records they create while logged in. don't record the user name, just id, because their name could be changed in the future right? like if they get married heh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `value3 = $_SESSION['username']` after the user has logged in and then insert it into the table.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username']

//connect to db

INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, $username) 

//close db connection
```

Session ID reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 1):

First as soon as user login to system (means when you are validating user data and generating session-token), you need to save the user-id in the session, then when ever he performs any insert operation you can get the user information based on session-token and insert it.

pseudo code

```
<?php
//When user logged-in
$_SESSION['user_id']=logged_in_user_id;

//When you need to insert
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

session_start();

// On the page your login form submits to

// Your authentication code is here make sure it is returning the USER ID if there is one

$_SESSION['username'] = $result->username; // use this for user name

$_SESSION['userid'] = $result->userid; // use this for user ID
?>
```

---

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Page that adds records
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3, $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']);
// I would rather see you use the user_id than the user name but you get the idea
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to track users then the easiest way i will recommend is creating a trigger.

Comment: Can you go a bit into detailing about this creating a trigger please