# userid when logged in php

Tags: php, session, url, authentication

How can you get the userid="" in the URL when the user is logged in. I have mysql database with table users. I wan to know the code which basically knows what is the id of the user that has logged in. And using sessions but not sure about the code.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you store the user's id in a session variable?

```
// Get it from the db, after login

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid;
```

**Example :**

[A simple Login Script (storing userID, etc into Session Variables)](http://www.knowledgesutra.com/discuss/tlddl-php-simple-login-tutorial-learn-simple-login.html)

Comment: but how can it know that which user it is, since there has to be some code which looks into the table users for the userid or doesnt it

Comment: @user1295105 Check out the example tutorial I sent you (I updated my initial answer)

Comment: in the example you shown me there is a line  $_SESSION["valid_id"] = $obj->id; how should i change this?  Should i put  $_SESSION["valid_id"] = $obj->userid;,

Answer (score 2):

```
$login_record = $YourLoginClassObject->Validate($email, $password);

if ($login_record != NULL ) //user record exist
{

$row = mysql_fetch_array($login_record);
$_SESSION["userid"] = trim($row["id"]);

// also you can store other information in session variables, like 
$_SESSION["first_name"] = $row["first_name"];
$_SESSION["last_name"] = $row["last_name"];


}
else
{
//user not exist
}
```

And after userid set in session you can retrieve it on any page using `$_SESSION["userid"]`

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Why you need userId in url, its creates security problem, if you pass userId and user changed the id in url then in backend you will end up doing the operation on wrong userId, always take the user details from session.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9895587/308251) for explanation on how you can store user info to session

Comment: thanks but I do not need the security, i just need to see how to do it for test

Answer (score 0):

You should store the userid in the session (for example ($_SESSION["userid"]))